# Restrict a type that key and value must be the same value

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

### **Hi all , i know we can use**

```
   enum FieldKeys {
      MONEY='MONEY',
      TEXT='TEXT',
      DATE='DATE'
    }
```

But i'm interested in how we can use generic to restrict key and value pair ?

```
type FieldType =  'MONEY'
  | 'TEXT'
  | 'DATE'

type Field<T extends FieldType> = {
    T:T
};

const obj :Field<FieldType> = {
    MONEY:"MONEY" /error
}
```

Comment: I don't get it, are you looking for [this](https://tsplay.dev/mA7x4w)?

Comment: yes :) thank you , i'm missing the  [P in K]: P ;)